# CasperJS with SlimerJS under linux

Tags: centos, phantomjs, casperjs, headless, slimerjs

I'm trying to execute a CasperJS script using SlimerJS (My tests must check html5 video which is not available using PhantomJS).

Using CasperJS on top of PhantomJS, all of my scripts work just fine, however with CasperJS on top of SlimerJS, I cannot execute any of them. instead, I just always get the following error message:

```html
[alex@webdev-srv test]$ xvfb-run casperjs --engine=slimerjs test2.js 

Script Error: Cannot find package.json at /home/alex/headless/phantomjs/test/package.json
       Stack:
         -> : 0

1474876419994   addons.repository       WARN    cacheEnabled: Couldn't get pref: extensions.getAddons.cache.enabled
```

I'm using CentOS 7 as VPS (No GUI), with Firefox being installed, and XVFB too.

How can I make it work? Or is there any solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried to create an empty package.json at that location? Or a minimally filled one?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: I think yes, I've just reinstalled NPM and the 2 packages (SlimerJS and CasperJS), now they seem to work